# Stack Sidebar Time

Tags: script, fun, left-sidebar

#### About

Makes a binary clock based on the Stack Overflow logo appear in the sidebar, inspired by [@g00glen00b's Stack Overflow Binary Clock™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319022/388442).

#### Screenshot

[image: Screen shot]

#### Download / Install

[Download on GitHub](https://github.com/a-stone-arachnid/Stack-Sidebar-Time/raw/master/StackSidebarTime.user.js).

#### Platform

Tested with GreaseMonkey.

#### Code

Made with jQuery and RxJS

Found a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)? Tell me on [GitHub](https://github.com/a-stone-arachnid/Stack-Sidebar-Time/issues).